# Convert .txt. file from windows-1251 to utf-8

Tags: conversion, notepad++, encoding, character-encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read the cyrillic text that is stored in .txt format. Once I open it with OpenOffice, it is OK. Once I open it with Notepad++, it shows unreadable symbols. Setting Windows-1251 prior opening the file doesn't help too much. The default value switches to Encode to UTF-8.

Is there a way to convert my text into UTF-8?

Comment: Is the file really windows-1251 encoded? How do you infer that? What “unreadable symbols” you see? Please show a small sample from the start, and the intended content for comparison.

Comment: Post a notepad++ screenshot and it should give a clue to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried today on another computer (with Cyrillic support). Everything is OK with this way: OpenOffice -> Copy the text into buffer -> Paste it in Notepad++ (UTF-8 without BOM)-> Save. Saved in UTF-8.